# layout views in slide menu in iOS

Tags: ios, layout

I am using SWRevealViewController as a slide menu in iOS. When I created the rear viewcontroller (the slide menu) a xib file was created with .m and .h files. I do not use autolayout and set the simulated metrics size as None.

The view seems all right when slide in and out on iPhone except that when the view is presented on iPad I want the positions of the menus to also change as the view becomes bigger but it doesn't.

Originally the view is as the image below shows:

[image]

In order to move the "settings" menu to the bottom I have made changes to the view settings of "settings image", "settings button" and the extra UIImageView as below:

[image]

but I want the settings menu to also locate at the bottom of the view just like it is now on iPhone. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used "Masonry" library to sort this out.
It is pretty amazing.

[Check out Masonry from GitHub](https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry)